# What does widget.something in flutter/dart actually call?

Tags: dart, flutter

I've seen people accessing certain variables via this: `widget.something`. What is `widget.` actually doing ? What does it reference.

For example (some random code I was working on):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Constants.dart';
import 'Lesson.dart';
import 'StaticMethods.dart';
import 'DetailPage.dart';
import 'package:garuda_academy_app/Authentication.dart';

class LessonPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LessonPage({Key key, this.auth, this.userId, this.onSignedOut, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  final BaseAuth auth;
  final VoidCallback onSignedOut;
  final String userId;

  @override
  _LessonPageState createState() => _LessonPageState();
}

class _LessonPageState extends State<LessonPage> {
  List lessons;

  @override
  void initState() {
    lessons = StaticMethods.getLessons();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ListTile makeListTile(Lesson lesson) => ListTile(
          contentPadding:
              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
          leading: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                border: new Border(
                    right: new BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.white24))),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.file_download, color: Colors.white),
              onPressed: (){},
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(
            lesson.title,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),

          subtitle: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(209, 224, 224, 0.2),
                        value: lesson.indicatorValue,
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.green)),
                  )),
              Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                    child: Text(lesson.level,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
              )
            ],
          ),
          trailing:
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right, color: Colors.white, size: 30.0),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => DetailPage(lesson: lesson)));
          },
        );

    Card makeCard(Lesson lesson) => Card(
          elevation: 8.0,
          margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromRGBO(64, 75, 96, .9)),
            child: makeListTile(lesson),
          ),
        );

    final makeBody = Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: lessons.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return makeCard(lessons[index]);
        },
      ),
    );

    final makeBottom = Container(
      height: 55.0,
      child: BottomAppBar(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.school, color: Colors.white),
              onPressed: () => StaticMethods.goToWidget(context, new LessonPage(title: LESSON_PAGE_TITLE, userId: widget.userId, ,)),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.flight_takeoff, color: Colors.white),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_box, color: Colors.white),
              onPressed: () {},
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    final topAppBar = AppBar(
      elevation: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
      title: Text(widget.title),
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    );

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
      appBar: topAppBar,
      body: makeBody,
      bottomNavigationBar: makeBottom,
    );
  }
}
```

If you notice all the way at the bottom topAppBar uses widget.title. Now this is accessing the title from `LessonPage`, which I don't get. What exactly does `widget.something` access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see the code for `State<T extends StatefulWidget>` inside framework.dart file you will find that `widget` is nothing but a getter for the private class variable `_widget`.

**framework.dart**

```
abstract class State<T extends StatefulWidget> extends Diagnosticable {
  T get widget => _widget;
  T _widget;
}
```

The abstract class `State` defines the `widget` property getter as below -

> A `State` object's configuration is the corresponding `StatefulWidget`
>   instance. This property is initialized by the framework before calling
>   `initState`. If the parent updates this location in the tree to a new
>   widget with the same `runtimeType` and `Widget.key` as the current
>   configuration, the framework will update this property to refer to the
>   new widget and then call `didUpdateWidget`, passing the old
>   configuration as an argument.

---

In simpler words, the `widget` property of the `State` class defines the present `StatefulWidget` that you `State` is referring to, and hence it can be used to access the run time properties of the `StatefulWidget`, which as you can see in your example can be one of the values from `title` to `userId`.

Hope this helps!