# Why i can't access the "title" properties instead of using "widget.title" in statefull widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

It is my statefulwidget , i have a variable title

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
   String? title='hello';
  
   MyHomePage({
     this.title,
  }) ;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

And here i want to access title but i can't understand why i need to use the widget.title .

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title!),
      ),
```

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56287100/13470875

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Short answer:*

The State class has a readonly property called `widget`. Which is what you are referencing to.

*Long answer:*

Now as Per Docs: **widget property**

> This property is initialized by the framework before calling
> initState. If the parent updates this location in the tree to a new
> widget with the same runtimeType and Widget.key as the current
> configuration, the framework will update this property to refer to the
> new widget and then call didUpdateWidget, passing the old
> configuration as an argument.

[reference link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/widget.html)